# Number input emptied after timeout event

Tags: jquery, html

I have a numeric input field I would like to automatically remove non numeric characters from:

```
<input type="number" name="bookISBN" id="bookISBN">
```

I am using the following jQuery which works for `text` input fields but when something is pasted into the `number` field it empties the field.

```js
    $('input').on('paste', function() {
      var $el = $(this);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $el.val(function(i, val) {
          return val.replace(/\D/g, '');
        })

      })
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Paste this: 978-1-58542-881-6
<br />Number:
<input type="number" name="bookISBN" id="bookISBN">
<br />Text:
<input type="text" name="text" id="text">
```

When you paste the isbn into the text field it keeps the only the numbers, but when you paste the same thing into the number field it empties.

Is there any way around this other than changing the number field to text?

Comment: type="number" excepts numbers, so it's pre validating the entry automatically. There is no event handler to handle this. Use type="text" and than parse it later to integer

Comment: But without the jQuery it allows pasting of the isbn with `-`'s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [clipboardData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent/clipboardData) when listening on paste event.

In order to preserve compatibility with IE you must test if clipboardData is attached to the window or to the event:

```js
$('input').on('paste', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var txt = '';
  if (window.clipboardData !== undefined) {
    txt = window.clipboardData.getData('text').replace(/\D/g, '');
  } else {
    txt = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text').replace(/\D/g, '');
  }
  if (!isNaN(txt) && txt.trim().length != 0)
    this.value = txt;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


Paste this: 978-1-58542-881-6
<br />Number:
<input type="number" name="bookISBN" id="bookISBN">
<br />Text:
<input type="text" name="text" id="text">
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you.